# Understanding C++ stack object allocation

Tags: c++

[ Updated based on comments. ]

I am trying to understand the behavior of C++ object allocation on the stack and how objcts are passed to functions and lambdas. Please see the below code, which I will explain briefly. A lot of it is boilerplate to make the output "pretty".

I have written a loop that allocates objects of type `thing` on the stack and passes them by value (via `std::move`) to a bound function that is spawned in a `std::thread`.

The output of this program looks like the following:

```
loop iteration 0
ctor 0x7ffca9a711bc(0)
move 0x7ffca9a711d8(0)
move 0x7ffca9a711e8(0)
move 0x561b3af602d0(0)
dtor 0x7ffca9a711e8(-1)
dtor 0x7ffca9a711d8(-1)
dtor 0x7ffca9a711bc(-1)
loop iteration 1
ctor 0x7ffca9a711bc(1)
move 0x7ffca9a711d8(1)
move 0x7ffca9a711e8(1)
move 0x561b3af60440(1)
copy 0x7f46cab41e94(0)
thread 0 starting
thing(0)
thread 0 ending
dtor 0x7f46cab41e94(0)
dtor 0x561b3af602d0(0)
dtor 0x7ffca9a711e8(-1)
dtor 0x7ffca9a711d8(-1)
dtor 0x7ffca9a711bc(-1)
loop iteration 2
copy 0x7f46ca340e94(1)
thread 1 starting
thing(1)
thread 1 ending
dtor 0x7f46ca340e94(1)
dtor 0x561b3af60440(1)
ctor 0x7ffca9a711bc(2)
move 0x7ffca9a711d8(2)
move 0x7ffca9a711e8(2)
move 0x561b3af60420(2)
dtor 0x7ffca9a711e8(-1)
dtor 0x7ffca9a711d8(-1)
dtor 0x7ffca9a711bc(-1)
loop iteration 3
copy 0x7f46cab41e94(2)
thread 2 starting
thing(2)
thread 2 ending
dtor 0x7f46cab41e94(2)
dtor 0x561b3af60420(2)
ctor 0x7ffca9a711bc(3)
move 0x7ffca9a711d8(3)
move 0x7ffca9a711e8(3)
move 0x561b3af60590(3)
dtor 0x7ffca9a711e8(-1)
dtor 0x7ffca9a711d8(-1)
dtor 0x7ffca9a711bc(-1)
loop iteration 4
copy 0x7f46cab41e94(3)
thread 3 starting
thing(3)
thread 3 ending
dtor 0x7f46cab41e94(3)
dtor 0x561b3af60590(3)
ctor 0x7ffca9a711bc(4)
move 0x7ffca9a711d8(4)
move 0x7ffca9a711e8(4)
move 0x561b3af60590(4)
dtor 0x7ffca9a711e8(-1)
copy 0x7f46cab41e94(4)
thread 4 starting
thing(4)
thread 4 ending
dtor 0x7f46cab41e94(4)
dtor 0x561b3af60590(4)
dtor 0x7ffca9a711d8(-1)
dtor 0x7ffca9a711bc(-1)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Invalid argument
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Clearly there are several allocations and de-allocations. The first allocation of a `thing` is always at address `0x7ffca9a711bc`, which I expect since I assume each loop iteration is pushing a variable onto the same region of the stack. Beyond that, there are a bunch of move and copy operations which *seem* to match up, but there is a segfault at the end that I cannot understand.

(The reason I am doing all this is to try to understand from first principles how to write a loop that creates a `boost::ip::tcp::socket` and passes it to a handling thread.)

Thank you!

Ihab Awad

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex print_mutex;

class thing {
public:
  thing(int i) : i_(i) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(print_mutex);
    std::cout << "ctor " << this << "(" << i_ << ")" << std::endl;
  }
  thing(thing&& t) : i_(t.i_) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(print_mutex);
    std::cout << "move " << this << "(" << i_ << ")" << std::endl;
    t.i_ = -1;
  }
  thing(const thing& t) : i_(t.i_) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(print_mutex);
    std::cout << "copy " << this << "(" << i_ << ")" << std::endl;
  }
  ~thing() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(print_mutex);
    std::cout << "dtor " << this << "(" << i_ << ")" << std::endl;
  }
  int i() const {
    return i_;
  }
private:
  int i_;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const thing& t) {
  os << "thing(" << t.i() << ")";
  return os;
}

void handle_thing(const int i, const thing t) {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(print_mutex);
  std::cout << "thread " << i << " starting" << std::endl;
  std::cout << t << std::endl;
  std::cout << "thread " << i << " ending" << std::endl;
}

int main(int arg, char** argv) {
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    std::cout << "loop iteration " << i << std::endl;
    thing t(i);
    std::thread thd(std::bind(handle_thing, i, std::move(t)));
    thd.detach();
    threads.push_back(std::move(thd));
  }
  for (auto i = threads.begin(); i < threads.end(); i++) {
    i->join();
  }
}
```

Comment: you are not printing the copy and move constructors.

Comment: Use lambdas instead of std::bind, it's slower and generates a lot of boilerplate assembly on some compilers (especially older ones). 
Check out Jason Turner's video to learn more: https://youtu.be/ZlHi8txU4aQ

Comment: You should print the value of `this` instead of only the text `ctor`, `dtor`. `thing`, etc.  That way, you will know, if you are missing allocation or deallocation calls.

Comment: Marcin: Thank you -- I used `std::bind` simply because the memory model of lambdas is one more thing that I was unsure about.

Comment: `std::thread` copies any parameters passed to it, if that helps at all.

Comment: Paul Sanders: I see, so the bound function object created by `std::bind` is copy-constructed by the `std::thread` ctor, along with whatever is inside it. And since there is an instance of `thing` inside the bound function, it is copy-constructed too. Which explains why my code will not work if I delete the copy constructor of `thing`.

Comment: *"but there is a segfault at the end that I cannot understand."* -- try looking at the [postcondition for `detach()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach#Postconditions) and the (third) [error conditions for `join()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join#Error_Conditions).

Comment: JaMiT: Thank you very much for the education! Removing `detach()` fixed the problem. Now I have working code.

Comment: And .. thank you to everyone who replied! I think I now understand much better the interactions between the various allocations.

For reference, what I was trying to do was to understand the Boost HTTP server example and reproduce its main elements in my code, and this discussion has made it possible for me to have working code!

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/http/server/sync/http_server_sync.cpp